# Assembly - Move with Zero Fill for Different Data Sizes

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers, irvine32

Currently learning assembly language using Masm. This is for an assignment in my class.

I must do certain calculations using 32-bit registers (EAX and EBX). I have to handle BYTE, WORD, and DWORD variables. Not really complicated. I do not really understand why am I getting so many errors when assembling the current code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    ; (declare variables)
    bNum01      BYTE    64
    bNum02      BYTE    32
    bNum03      BYTE    16
    bSum        BYTE    ?
    bDiff       BYTE    ?
    bResult     BYTE    ?

    wNum01      WORD    64
    wNum02      WORD    32
    wNum03      WORD    16
    wSum        WORD    ?
    wDiff       WORD    ?
    wResult     WORD    ?

    dwNum01     DWORD   64
    dwNum02     DWORD   32
    dwNum03     DWORD   16
    dwSum       DWORD   ?
    dwDiff      DWORD   ?
    dwResult    DWORD   ?
    dwTotal     DWORD   ?


.code
main PROC
    ; (insert executable instructions)
    movzx   eax,bNum01
    add eax,bNum02
    add eax,bNum03
    movzx   bSum,eax

    movzx   eax,bNum02
    add eax,bNum03
    sub eax,bNum01
    movzx   bDiff,eax

    movzx   eax,bSum
    add eax,bDiff
    movzx   bResult,eax

    mov  esi,OFFSET   bSum
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF bSum
    mov  ebx,TYPE     bSum
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value

    mov  esi,OFFSET   bDiff
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF bDiff
    mov  ebx,TYPE     bDiff
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value   

    mov  esi,OFFSET   bResult
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF bResult
    mov  ebx,TYPE     bResult
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value


; WORD main processing


    movzx   ebx,wNum01
    add ebx,wNum02
    add ebx,wNum03
    movzx   wSum,ebx

    movzx   ebx,wNum02
    add ebx,wNum03
    sub ebx,wNum01
    movzx   wDiff,ebx

    movzx   ebx,wSum
    add ebx,wDiff
    movzx   wResult,ebx

    mov  esi,OFFSET   wSum
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF wSum
    mov  ebx,TYPE     wSum
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value

    mov  esi,OFFSET   wDiff
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF wDiff
    mov  ebx,TYPE     wDiff
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value   

    mov  esi,OFFSET   wResult
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF wResult
    mov  ebx,TYPE     wResult
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value


; DWORD main processing

    mov     eax,0
    mov eax,dwNum01
    add eax,dwNum02
    add eax,dwNum03
    mov dwSum,eax

    mov eax,0
    mov eax,dwNum02
    add eax,dwNum03
    sub eax,dwNum01
    mov dwDiff,eax

    mov eax,0
    mov eax,dwSum
    add eax,dwDiff
    mov dwResult,eax

    mov  esi,OFFSET   dwSum
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF dwSum
    mov  ebx,TYPE     dwSum
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value

    mov  esi,OFFSET   dwDiff
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF dwDiff
    mov  ebx,TYPE     dwDiff
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value   

    mov  esi,OFFSET   dwResult
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF dwResult
    mov  ebx,TYPE     dwResult
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value

; Main side for Dwtotal


    mov eax,0
    movzx eax,bSum

    add ebx,wSum
    add eax,dwSum

    mov dwTotal,eax


    mov  esi,OFFSET   dwTotal
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF dwTotal
    mov  ebx,TYPE     dwTotal
    call DumpMem             ; call Dump Memory for selected offset value


    exit
main ENDP

    ; (additional procedures)
END main
```

The errors start in the line where I add bNum02 to the EAX register after using MOVZX to move the value of Bnum01 to the EAX register. It just says that it is an "invalid instruction operands". Which, from what I understand, it is telling me "That's not how it works". I try to researched but nothing really made sense.

Thank you to anyone that takes the time to explain.

Comment: BTW, I prefer the original Intel syntax, where any memory reference is inside brackets, so I suggest you to use `movzx eax,[bNum01]` to make the memory reference visible (and identical to the case when register addressing is used, like `movzx eax,byte ptr [esi]`). MASM doesn't require them, but some other assemblers do. IMO it's easier to read source with brackets (to quickly find all memory accesses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operands of an instruction must have the same type resp. size. You cannot move a `BYTE` variable to a `DWORD` register. The special instructions for that purpose are `MOVZX` and `MOVSX` which convert the smaller operand appropriate. Storing in this way (`movzx   bSum,eax` ) is not possible, but you can use the least significant byte of `EAX` - the `AL` register:

```
movzx   eax,bNum01
movzx   ebx,bNum02
add eax, ebx
movzx   ebx,bNum03
add eax, ebx
mov   bSum, al
```

The least significant WORD of `EBX` is called `BX` register (EAX->AX, EBX->BX, ECX->CX, EDX->DX):

```
mov   wSum, bx
```

Comment: When it comes to `movzx    bSum,al` I get an error that says "Memory operand not allowed in context".

Another question: I am still confused when it comes to registers. Are they connected in some way? I only know Python and some OOP but that's about it. I think Assembly is being way harder than what it should

Comment: @Roy740: My bad, sorry. Change `MOVZX` to `MOV`. Consider: `mov   bSum, eax` gives no error, but writes the **full** DWORD to the variables. It will overwrite subsequent variables.

Comment: @Roy740: Assembly is as hard as the processor is designed. Imagine registers as a kind of quick memory inside the processor. The names (EAX, AX, AL) are just a way to access it. They can be "connected", e.g. `AL` is a part of `EAX`. Take a look in a tutorial. A lot of processor instructions can only work with registers, not on the memory.

Comment: @Roy740 assembly is actually quite easy, there's just few instructions, memory, and bits containing 0 and 1, simple (sort of, at least from the point of view of the CPU designer) logical rules, and everything being deterministic. You just have to get that machine-like mindset, understanding where those bits exists, and how those instructions operate them. The tedious part is to write anything complex in it, and the entry level may be a bit steep, if you don't "see" the particular bits behind it. For example `eax` is like 32 bits inside CPU, low 16/8 of them having alias `ax`/`al`.